# JavaScript - Class toggling is removing the class and not adding in next click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have set an eventlistener on i tag with class=glyphcolor What I want to do is that whenever I see an element of class checkglyph1 it has to toggle the class i.e if class is there it has to be removed and if not add.What the checkglyph1 class does is it changes the color of the text.

### Actual Result

([image to the output I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGrRb.png))

At first click I see that first element is toggled here by default I have already set it.On next click it gets removed instead of the toggle .

**HTML section:**

```
<div class="row datasection">
    <div class="todo">
        <div class="databox col s6 waves-effect">
            <p class="checkglyph1 ">Task to do</p>
            <!--   </div>  -->
            <a>
                <i class="material-icons checkglyph checkglyph1 glyphcolor">check</i>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var glyph= document.querySelector('.glyphcolor');
var par=  document.getElementsByClassName('checkglyph1');
console.log(par[0]);
console.log(par[1]);
glyph.addEventListener('click', function () {
    /* body... */
    console.log("Qw");
    par[0].classList.toggle("checkglyph1");
    console.log(par[0]);
    par[1].classList.toggle("checkglyph1");

})
```

**CSS:**

```
.datasection .todo .databox {
    background-color: teal;
    margin-left: 120px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.databox p{
    display: inline-block;
}

.databox a .checkglyph{
    display: inline-block;
    color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    left: 90%;
    top: 25%;
}

.databox a .checkglyph:hover{
    display: inline-block;
}

.databox a .checkglyph1{
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.databox .checkglyph1{
    color: white;
    cursor: text;
}
```

Comment: `if (par[0].classList.contains("checkglyph1")) {
    par[0].classList.toggle("checkglyph1");
} else {
    par[0].classList.toggle("checkglyph1");
}` makes zero sense, it is the same code in if and else....

Comment: The if - else statement is not necessary since you're doing the same thing either case. Not that it is the problem, just pointing out.

Comment: @GermanC done the edits but still the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementsByClassName is a LIVE Html Collection. Remove the class, the item is removed from the collection.

```js
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("foo")
console.log("before", elems.length);
elems[0].classList.remove("foo");

console.log("after", elems.length);
```

```css
.foo { color: red; }
```

```html
<div class="foo">1</div>
<div class="foo">2</div>
```

Comment: but on next click it should get toggled i.e it should return back right?

Comment: How can it be toggled back when the element is no longer in the collection to select? If you want it to remain in the collection, you need to add a class or something that is static.

Comment: I get it...but how do I ammend the code then.I used classes so that it targets   all occurences.

Comment: Set a class that you do not add/alter/remove